# Linq Group By Issue - can't get the syntax right

Tags: linq

For some reason I am totally stuck on the syntax for LINQ Group in vb.net - can somebody help me sort out the following?

I have 5000 objects like this:

```
Public Class ExpressionReturn
    Implements IComparable(Of ExpressionReturn)

    Public Property Price As Price
    Public Property Value As Nullable(Of Decimal)
    Public Property Expression As Expression
    Public Property Rank As Single
End Class
```

I am trying to group them together on price.priceid (an integer) and then return a sum of the ranks to have a series of object such as this:

```
Public Class RankReturn
    Public Property Price As Price
    Public Property Expression As Expression
    Public Property RankSum As Single
End Class
```

I'm stuck on the syntax for Group By in Linq... can anyone help?

Comment: Download [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and check its examples.

Comment: How were you planning to combine the `Expression` values of those 5000 objects for your result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for coming back to me - after playing with the code with a clear head it seems a big difference between c# (which has most of the examples) and vb.net is that you seem to have to return the same objects in the select statement as are being grouped.

I've now ditched this approach as grouping is much slower than I expected - I've used a dictionary to store the sum that I need which is much quicker 5ms compared to 700ms!